# PHP + Writing Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I know how to write cookies and do so often enough but I have a different situation this time.

On this site users can enable autologin which basically saves an encrypted cookie with password and username and then uses these to login.

Once logged in they are iframed onto a different site/domain which they use until logoff.

When iframed into this other site/domain they can choose to enable/disable the autologin.
I've setup a PHP CURL call that sends back to the login domain the information required to set or remove the password cookie.

The catch is I can't seem to update the cookie for a domain that I'm not currently viewing in the browser. Does anyone know if a user must be viewing a domain to write cookies for it or if they could be on another domain and using a CURL Call update a cookie for a different domain they were previously on?

thx

Comment: Note: I'm CURL'ing back to the domain I want to write the cookies for so I believe the required domain is writing cookies for itself - note: trying to write Cookies for domain A from domain B...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't know how to write cookies.

> saves an encrypted cookie with password and username

So you're exposing the user to MITM, replay and brute force decryption attacks.

> When iframed into this other site/domain they can choose to enable/disable the autologin. I've setup a PHP CURL call that sends back to the login domain the information required to set or remove the password cookie.

So the cookie is bound to the site which presents the iframe (call it www.front.com). However the authentication applies to the site within the iframe (call it www.back.com): this implies there are very few, but very elaborate/complex ways for the information stored in the www.front.com cookie to be transmitted to the www.back.com site.

> The catch is I can't seem to update the cookie for a domain that I'm not currently viewing in the browser

The solution to this should be obvious if you've already solved the problem of sending the cookie data securely to www.back.com

You've really painted yourself into a corner. That the solution to this is not obvious implies that you've not addressed the security issues inherent in accessing the site up the point where you want to unset the cookie. I'd strongly recommend you start again from scratch - or at least try to explain what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: thanks for your reply - is there any chance I can chat to you further about this? maybe on skype?